# How to confirm if user wants to make a marker on googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps, markers

Right now, my app can search places and when I search them they make a marker on the spot. But I want to make the user confirm if they really want to make a marker there. Is there a way to make a popup info with a yes no checkbox on the marker when it's searched? 
I know there's a default infowindow when the marker is clicked. But I want to make button on the info window like "do you want to make a marker here?" question and there's a yes or no button there.
Also if I could make that popupinfo thing I'd like to make a way to remove the marker when the user wants to 
Any ideas?

This is my java code

```
package com.example.yoons.honey;


public class RealMap extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

private Button searchButton;
GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.real_map);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);

    searchButton = new Button(this);
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(search);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap =googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    /*LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/
}

private  View.OnClickListener search=new View.OnClickListener(){ //검색버튼
    public void onClick(View v){
        onMapSearch(v);
    }
};


public void onMapSearch(View view) {
    int markercount=0;//주소개수 사용
    EditText locationSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;
    if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (addressList != null && addressList.size() != 0) {
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker")/*.draggable(true)*/);
            markercount++;

           // mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15f));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "location not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker")
```

This line here perform the add marker action. So what you can do is create alertdialog and handle the yes no in OnClickListener.

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                //Yes button clicked
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker");
                markercount++;

                // mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15f));
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                //No button clicked
                break;
        }
    } 
};
```

and in your onMapSearch function, build the alert dialog like this:

```
if (addressList != null && addressList.size() != 0) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
        .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "location not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: It says ''cannot resolve method getContext()'' in
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

Comment: Are u implement it in activity class? You can pass in context parameter. How about getApplicationContext() method.

Comment: I tried getApplicationContext() but it doesn't work either. The app shuts down . I dont' know why

Comment: can u paste logcat.